# The following resource(s) failed to create: [PhoneHomeCustomResource]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Failed to create stack with PhoneHomeCustomResource. Getting error as   Invalid service token.

The service token I provided is:

```
            "ServiceToken": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:*********:test-standard-queue",
```

Comment: You need to provide more details around what you are trying to do and how. And what stage you are getting the error? Are you sure SQS Arn can be passed as a ServiceToken?

Comment: Just want to add a bit more information to the previous comment.

"The service token specifies where AWS CloudFormation sends requests to, such as to an Amazon SNS topic ARN or to an AWS Lambda function ARN", so in opinion SQS arn wouldn't work.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html